# Fixed file name for upload.php script

Tags: php, xml, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to upload a XML file to a server and this file is named as `data.xml`. The data will always be overwritten everytime they are accessed.

My doubt is how to set the file-name to a fixed name with `.xml` extension as the extension filter? I want to place the file in the same folder as the `upload.php`.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
<?php

$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ", basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']), " has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: why do you want fixed file name?

Comment: This file is later going to be accessed by another system. The file is to be read for every time the user taps.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<?
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . 'data.xml'; 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
 } else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }
?>
```

Comment: What does the basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) serve for?

Comment: @DesperateLearner You could check the manual for [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php). These things are just a google search away. Try to find an answer on the web before posting a question please.